# Facing the issue while fitting my model (bi-lstm + crf). ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list)

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, lstm, crf, bilstm

I am trying to solve a problem which contains bi-LSTM and CRF, while fitting the model, i am facing this issue ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list). Below is the structure of the dataframe.
Columns named "CompanyId" that contains integer. "Name" that contains string. "TableTypeCode" that is a string that is constant and is same as "BS". and final column named "BlockName". I want to train a model using bidirectional lstm and crf . Input being "CompanyId", "Name", and "TableTypeCode" and should predict "BlockName".

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.layers import Dense
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, LSTM, Dense, TimeDistributed, Bidirectional
from keras.models import Model
!pip install tensorflow-addons==0.16.1
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
X = df[['CompanyId', 'Name', 'TableTypeCode']]
y = df['BlockName']
# Preprocess the data
# One-hot encode the 'CompanyId' and 'TableTypeCode' columns
X = pd.get_dummies(X, columns=['CompanyId', 'TableTypeCode'])
# Tokenize the 'Name' column
X['Name'] = X['Name'].apply(str)
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
X['Name'] = X['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split())
X['Name'] = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X['Name'])
# Encode the target column
encoder = LabelEncoder()
y = encoder.fit_transform(y)
y = to_categorical(y)
# Split the data into training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
n_classes = df['BlockName'].nunique()
# Define the model architecture
input_ = Input(shape=(X.shape[1],))
embedding = Embedding(input_dim=X.shape[1], output_dim=50)(input_)
lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=100))(embedding)
output = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')(lstm)
model = Model(input_, output)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

There was no issue till the last line of code. Help me fix this and train my model.